# Blocking amount on Paypal

Tags: paypal

Is it possible that the amount paid by customer via PayPal on my site will not be deducted from the user's account, only blocked and I (the merchant) will determine after a few days whether to withdraw the amount or unblock it and return it?

trying to get right answer on my case

Comment: Yes it's possible,such thing called Authorization hold , please see more info here

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/customize/authorization-honor/#:~:text=An%20authorization%20places%20a%20hold,on%20the%20authorized%20funding%20instrument.

Answer (score 0):

A standard PayPal Checkout integration can be set up for separate authorization and capture steps.  [The documentation on how to do so is here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/customize/authorization/), essentially set intent to 'authorize' and then capture within 29 days within the PayPal.com account or with a capture API call.